# Android CountDownTimer - onTick() don't update UI after reopening app

Tags: android, countdowntimer

Basic count down app with a textView and a start/stop button.
If I close the app while the countDownTimer is running it will continue to work until finish. The problem is when I reopen the app while it's counting down the onTick() method don't update the new instance of the TextView.
Is there a way to make this work?

If I understand correctly CountDownTimer runs in it's own service.
My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView display;
    Button button;
    MyCountdownTimer myTimer;
    long starTime = 15 * 1000;
    long interval = 1000;
    boolean timerIsStarted = false;

    private static final String TAG = "LogMainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myTimer = new MyCountdownTimer(starTime, interval);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewID);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonID);
    }


    public void startButtonOnClick(View view) {
        if(!timerIsStarted){
            timerIsStarted = true;
            myTimer.start();
        } else {
            timerIsStarted = false;
            display.setText("00");
            myTimer.cancel();
        }
    }

    public class MyCountdownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

        public MyCountdownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished));
            display.setText(String.valueOf(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished)));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            timerIsStarted = false;
            Log.d(TAG, "Finished!");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finished!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            display.setText("Finished!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @diogojme  put that in an answer! :)

Comment: @petey I did already

Answer (score 0):

It's because you start your countDown timer when the user click on the button. For it work you have to add `myTimer.start();` in the onCreate method. But remember, it is creating a new instance of the CountDown, this will start counting from the 0. So you have to save the last time then start from this time.